# How to access to a NSArray, after extract values from a json file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I'm working with json file and I have saved my response in a NSArray.

```c
 NSArray *result = [response JSONValue];
NSLog(@"value = %@", result);
```

When I print my array, in console I obtain this:

```json
(
    {
    user =         {
        "created_at" = "2011-06-07T16:20:16Z";
        id = 1;
        name = "john";
        "updated_at" = "2011-06-07T16:20:16Z";
    };
},
    {
    user =         {
        "created_at" = "2011-06-08T00:03:54Z";
        id = 25;
        name = "david";
        "updated_at" = "2011-06-08T00:03:54Z";
    };
}
```

)

My question is this - how can access to the value "name" and save the value (john,david) in an another array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Key-Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html):

```
NSArray *names = [result valueForKeyPath:@"user.name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Store your individual array elements in a NSDictionary and then access those key/pair values.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to access the `name` from `result Array` and insert into `mutableArray(arr)`
Below code snippet may helpful for you:

```
     NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     for(int i = 0; i<[result count];i++)
    {                                                                                                                                               
    NSDictionary *dict = [result objectAtIndex:i];
     [arr addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"name"]];
}
```

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 0'

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *result = [response JSONValue];
NSMutableArray *nameArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSEnumerator* enumerator=[result objectEnumerator];
NSDictionary* dictionary;
while (dictionary=[enumerator nextObject]) 
{
    [nameArr addObject:[dictionary objectForKey:@"name"]];
}
```